# run a phpunit testcase file from a php file

Tags: php, selenium, console, phpunit

I am currently using phpunit for doing some automated tasks using selenium. 
I would like to call the phpunit file in an ajax call from javascript on the client side. 
The problem is that the phpunit test case file runs only by using the console command "phpunit filename.php". If I run the testcase file in the ajax call, i guess that it would be interpreted as a normal php file.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what that would do for you? I find hard to imagine why would you want to do that. Running a normal testcase file trough php should not generate output since it most likely contains only a class declaration.

Comment: I want to perform some automated tasks using phpunit and selenium. The problem is that this automated task that i've created needs to exchange real-time data with a larger framework code. So I am intending on calling this unit test file from javascript in ajax-process.

Comment: Another solution was provided to a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430620/how-to-run-phpunit-from-a-php-script

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it but you may be able to use:

```
passthru('phpunit --colors yourfilehere.php')
```

Or one of the `èxec`family of functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) but.. please.. evaluate better ways first and use them with great care, lest you lose control of your server. I tend to not use those functions if it is at all possible.